# Run macro based on current time

Tags: excel, vba

Please review the screenshot attached for ease of reference

[image: Snapshot of shares query]

LTP in column'AC' refers to Last traded Price of a share. **LTP changes every second** and is automatically imported from another software.

1. Column AF1: time gets updated automatically
2. Column AQ: Gets updated as per the below code

The code used for column AQ should also be used for columns AS,AT but I am facing issue

- Column AS: Whenever time is 9:15 AM. The entire column should be updated as per the prices in column AC
- Column AT: Whenever time is 9:30 AM. The entire column should be updated as per the prices in column AC

Please help me in this issue and excuse me if the framing of question is incorrect

```
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

 Range("AC3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Range("AQ3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    [AQ:AQ].Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Rows("2:2").Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
```

Comment: You could use a `Workbook_Open()` event and trigger each schedule manually (giving the exact time you need) or if it goes on every 15 mins for X hours, fire the event at the starting time and then your main macro will have another one firing it every 15 mins until X hour.

Comment: @Damian Could you please give a working example of your answer.Your help would be highly appreciated as I am new to VBA

Comment: Could you please then give the frame of time you want your macro to work? From X to Y in 15 min intervals?

Comment: @Damian Trading starts at 09:15 and closes at 15:30. So I need for every 15 minutes from 09:15 to 15:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me while but here it comes:

First you need to insert this code in `ThisWorkbook`module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Starting Time
End Sub
```

Then insert a new module and paste this code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const TimeFrame As Byte = 15 'this will let you edit how many minutes you want between events
Sub Starting(CurrentTime As Date)
    
    'This macro controls when the update will be fired.
    
    Dim StartTime As Date: StartTime = "09:15" 'Starting Time
    Dim EndTime As Date: EndTime = "15:30" 'End time
    Dim NextFrame As Date: NextFrame = TimeSerial(Hour(CurrentTime), Application.RoundUp(Minute(CurrentTime) / TimeFrame, 0) * TimeFrame, 0)
    If NextFrame < StartTime Then
        Application.OnTime StartTime + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0), "UpdateValuesForTime"
    ElseIf NextFrame > EndTime Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.OnTime NextFrame + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0), "UpdateValuesForTime"
    End If
    'The  "+ TimeSerial(0, 1, 0)" is to start the procedure 1 minute after the frame for if it takes a while to update the values.
    
End Sub
Sub UpdateValuesForTime()
    
    Dim CurrentTime As Date
    CurrentTime = TimeSerial(Hour(Time), (Application.RoundUp(Minute(Time) / TimeFrame, 0) * TimeFrame) - TimeFrame, 0)
    'Turn Time to String like in your sheet to find the column
    Dim StrTime As String: StrTime = Chr(34) & Format(CurrentTime, "hh:mm") & Chr(34)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName") 'change this name
        'Find last row for column AC
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row
        'Find correct column depending on your time
        Dim Col As Long: Col = .Rows(2).Find(StrTime).Column
        'Paste values from column AC to the column which time fits.
        .Range(.Cells(3, Col), .Cells(LastRow, Col)).Value = .Range("AC2:AC" & LastRow).Value
    End With
    'Call the starting macro again to schedule the next event
    Starting Time
    
End Sub
```

this should go by itself just by openning the workbook from 9:15 to 15:30. You'll see the starting and end times are easy to change if needed. Also remember to change the sheet name where the macro will run.

Comment: Sorry I have been inactive for a couple of days. Thank you very much. You have saved a lot of time and mental effort. Keep growing.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you use Windows Task Scheduler to control the execution.

You just need a macro on `Workbook_Open`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim lngUsedCol As Long
    
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Range(Range("AC3"), Range("AC3").End(xlDown)).Copy
    
    Range("AQ3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    lngUsedCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, lngUsedCol) = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
    
    Range(Range("AC3"), Range("AC3").End(xlDown)).Copy
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, lngUsedCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Task Scheduler will open the file based on the pre-configured schedule. With this approach there would be no need of a manually intervention.

Use this link to check out how to schedule a task using Task Scheduler - [how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10)

Comment: You are missing the point here, `AQ3` column is for a given time, for example 09:15, but this needs to change depending on the time.

Comment: I thought the data has to be copied first to `AQ` i.e. Mod LT and then to the respective time column. In the above approach, the user doesn't have to input the time as the column header. The script itself updates the column name based on the time it was triggered.